# Missing Tomcat8 conf directory

Tags: tomcat, configuration, repository, debian, tomcat8

I've just installed **Tomcat8** version *8.0.24-1* from **Debian 8** [repository](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/testing/) by `aptitude install tomcat8`. I tried to play around with Tomcat, starting and stopping it. When I tried to shut it down by running `./bin/shutdown.sh`, I noticed that shutdown operation fails - it complains that `conf` directory is missing. I checked it and that is right - indeed it is missing!

Why?

I downloaded Tomcat8 from official Tomacat [website](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi) to compare content of both directories - from the Debian's repo and from Tomcat's website. It turned out that directory from Tomcat's website is complete and contains `conf` directory.

Why is that?
Why package from Debian's repo doesn't contain `conf` directory and bunch of configuration files?

BTW: neither `tomcat8-examples` nor `tomcat8-admin` packages contain `conf` directory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/usr/share/tomcat8` contains the application.

All the **var**iable parts (`conf`, `logs`, `webapps`, etc.) are normally in `/var/lib/tomcat8`

Answer (score 1):

Thats true , the problem is that tomcat8 is setup to have a conf in share as well.. this seems to be because catalina.sh and/or startup.sh fail to specify a separate base even tho the debian maintainers are using one.

The only reasonable fix seems to be to manually edit your catalina.sh and set CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/tomcat8

This doesn't fix netbeans, which has permissions issues since a lot of that var stuff is owned by root or linked to it... copying those bits to share or adding tomcat8 group to /etc files... please someone have a better answer!

Comment: did u find a better awnser? im having the exact same problem